# Copy part of row if value is met in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, vba

I have an Excelsheet looking similar to this (Sheet1):

[image]

What I want is that for all rows (which is dynamic) that Column J contains **NEW-LOCATION** I would like to copy the information on those rows from column A, C, D and E to another sheet (Sheet2) but I would also be able to add new information on the new sheet like below:

[image]

The green part is copied from Sheet1 and the Yellow part is stuff I write myself in Sheet2.
It should be dynamic and if the value **NEW-LOCATION** is removed in Sheet1 the row with information in sheet2 should be deleted.

Anyone has any idea how to manage this? It doesn´t have to be code it can be with formula, conditional formatting or any other default Excel stuff that can manage this.

Comment: `Information` column is either "NEW-LOCATION" or blank, correct?

Comment: Column is a dropdown with dynamic amount of value to choose between. But It can also be blank.

Comment: What column's/concatetion of columns' values in both sheets explicitly select one row? What I mean is: how do you identify which row should be deleted in `Sheet2` given we remove **NEW-LOCATION** from `Sheet1`? Quick hint for you to think about the problem: you can use `Private Sub Worksheet_Change` to check if values on this `Sheet` were changed. Condition: `If Not IsNothing(Intersect(Target, Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("J"))) Then...`

Comment: Location Column A stores uniq numeric values eg. 001, 002, 345 etc.

Comment: Please clarify, as your Column A stores {North, South, East, West} atm.

Comment: The pictures above is just examples but Column A contains only numbers formatted 001, 002, 123, 452 etc.
I didn´t know if that was relevant until you asked for some way to identify which row to remove in sheet2.

Comment: Updated pictures so that it matches reality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test it before using it on actual data, I might have overlooked something.
What I came up with so far, I commented parts of code for clarity, note that it is `Sub Worksheet_Change` module for Sheet1, paste it accordingly:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Main As Worksheet, Secondary As Worksheet
    Dim iCell As Range, FoundRange As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    '   Define worksheets for simplicity
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set Main = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set Secondary = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    '   Calculate last row on Sheet2 (by column "A")
    lRow = Secondary.Range("A" & Secondary.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '   Check if changes were made in columns "J" (Information)
    '   If changes weren't made in column "J" leave this sub
    If Intersect(Target, Main.Columns("J")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    '   Loop through each changed cell of column "J"
    For Each iCell In Intersect(Target, Main.Columns("J")).Cells
        '   Find location on Sheet2
        'Main.Range("A" & iCell.Row).Value
        Set FoundRange = Secondary.Range("A2:A" & lRow).Find(Main.Range("A" & iCell.Row).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        '   If value of the changed cell is "NEW-LOCATION"..
        If iCell.Value = "NEW-LOCATION" Then
            '   And it didn't find this location on Sheet2..
            If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
                '   Add new location
                Secondary.Range("A" & lRow + 1).Value = Main.Range("A" & iCell.Row).Value
                Secondary.Range("B" & lRow + 1 & ":D" & lRow + 1 & "").Value = Main.Range("C" & iCell.Row & ":E" & iCell.Row & "").Value
                lRow = lRow + 1
            End If
        '   If value of the changed cell is NOT "NEW-LOCATION"..
        Else
            '   And it found this location in Sheet2..
            If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
                '   Delete row with this location
                FoundRange.EntireRow.Delete
                lRow = lRow - 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems to work as intended. Many thanks #AntiDrondert

Comment: @MarkusSacramento No problem :)